# How many registered users are there?

Tags: support, statistics

Can I somewhere see the number of registered users on  our site [ without multiplying the number of pages by  36, the number of users per page] ?

Comment: I think there are $n$ registered users, and $k$ unregistered users. Both $n$ and $k$ are in $\Bbb N$, and are probably smaller than $10^{8000}$.

Comment: An aside: to find how many ***total*** users there are (both registered and unregistered), use this page: http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible way to get an idea about this number is to look at the right (i.e. total reputation tab) of [this page](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/alltime/math). As of today, it seems that there are $65\,508$ registered users.

On the other hand, I am sure that a lot of people create new account for every new question they have, and therefore the number of actual users is (much?) less than the number of registered accounts.

Comment: Dear O.L. : perfect answer + clever remark $\implies$ upvote+acceptance of answer+many thanks :-)

Comment: When I decrease the time period over which the reputation is totaled on that page, the number of users increases. When I set it to "Week", I see $72\,006$ users. This seems odd. The number of users at $100\,000+$ stays at $6$.

Comment: @robjohn I have also noticed this. In the first version of my answer I gave a link to "week" and later corrected it by "all-time". In the range 100-5000 reputation this gives quite different numbers, and it is "all-time" which seems to correspond to what one obtains by multiplying the number of relevant pages by 36.

Comment: Dear O.L., the multiplication by 36 gives 57960, whereas the "all time" page of yor link  gives 65524.   Do you also get such a discrepancy?

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg , yes. But, for example, for users with +500 reputation, we obtain $60\times 36+26=2186$. This is rather close to currently indicated $2206$ ("all-time") and very far from $682$ ("week").

Comment: Thanks again, O.L.

Comment: Oh hey, almost 2^16.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: You must have been studying 2-groups lately :)